# Add user custom account field to WooCommerce checkout

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, account, user-data

I have added to admin users a custom meta field using the following code:``

```
function wporg_usermeta_form_field_birthday( $user )
{
    ?>
    
    <table class="form-table" id="table-form-dob" >
        <tr>
            <th><h3 style="margin: 0">Extra Meta Fields</h3></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>
                <label for="user_dob">Birthday</label>
            </th>
            <td>
                <input type="date"
                       class="regular-text ltr"
                       id="user_dob"
                       name="user_dob"
                       value="<?= esc_attr( get_user_meta( $user->ID, 'user_dob', true ) ) ?>"
                       title="Please use YYYY-MM-DD as the date format."
                       pattern="(19[0-9][0-9]|20[0-9][0-9])-(1[0-2]|0[1-9])-(3[01]|[21][0-9]|0[1-9])"
                       required>
                
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <script>
        jQuery(function($){
        jQuery('#table-form-dob tr').insertAfter(jQuery('#display_name').parentsUntil('tr').parent());
    });
    </script>
    <?php
}
  
function wporg_usermeta_form_field_birthday_update( $user_id )
{
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_user', $user_id ) ) {
        return false;
    }
    return update_user_meta(
        $user_id,
        'user_dob',
        $_POST['user_dob']
    );
}
  
add_action(
    'show_user_profile',
    'wporg_usermeta_form_field_birthday'
);
  
add_action(
    'edit_user_profile',
    'wporg_usermeta_form_field_birthday'
);
  
add_action(
    'personal_options_update',
    'wporg_usermeta_form_field_birthday_update'
);
  
add_action(
    'edit_user_profile_update',
    'wporg_usermeta_form_field_birthday_update'
);

register_meta('user', 'user_dob', array(
  "type" => "string",
  "show_in_rest" => true // this is the key part
));
```

I want to add this same field In woocommerce checkout page, so when the user get registered in woocommerce checkout page, we should be able to see this "Birthday" field *(`user_dob`)* in admin user profile/ edit section.

also, I am accessing user meta in rest API currently its showing meta in rest API after user saver values in check it should value in wp rest API.

How can I add this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following that will add `user_dob` custom field to checkout account registration fields:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'add_checkout_account_birthday_field' );
function add_checkout_account_birthday_field( $fields ){
    $fields['account']['user_dob'] = array(
        'type'              => 'date',
        'label'             => __("Birthday", "woocommerce"),
        'placeholder'       => __("Please use YYYY-MM-DD as the date format.", "woocommerce"),
        'class'             => array('form-row-wide regular-text ltr'),
        'required'          => true,
        'custom_attributes' => ['pattern' => '(19[0-9][0-9]|20[0-9][0-9])-(1[0-2]|0[1-9])-(3[01]|[21][0-9]|0[1-9])'],
    );
    return $fields;
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_customer', 'save_checkout_account_birthday_field', 10, 2 );
function save_checkout_account_birthday_field( $customer, $data ){
    if ( isset($_POST['user_dob']) && ! empty($_POST['user_dob']) ) {
         $customer->update_meta_data( 'user_dob', sanitize_text_field($_POST['user_dob']) );
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

[image]

Once order is placed the birth date is saved to user data and displayed in admin user "Birthday" field.